# Laravel 5.1 with php 5.5 to update to php 7 issue on OSX

Tags: php, macos, laravel, nginx

I'm currently running a Laravel 5.1 app with php 5.5 and nginx on my Mac OSX, I want to update php to php 7.0 so I typed the following in terminal:

```
brew unlink php55
brew uninstall php55
brew install --with-fpm --with-mysql php70
```

It works and after that,

```
php -v
```

gives me the following response:

```
PHP 7.0.0RC4 (cli) (built: Oct  5 2015 03:44:48) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

I then restarted nginx, but when I tried to echo phpinfo in my existing Laravel app, it still says current version of php is 5.5, what else do I need to setup for Laravel 5.1 to run on top of my newly installed php 7.0?

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out I didn't restart php-fpm, so after killed the old php-fpm and then

```
php70-fpm start
nginx -s reload
```

Everything worked out perfectly.